# StubHub API Not Loading Ticket Information

Tags: python

I am getting a 403 Forbidden error when trying to load information for the following event. Any ideas what is causing this??

```
import json
from pprint import pprint
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = 'http://www.stubhub.com/ticketAPI/restSvc/event/104836772'

data = json.load(urlopen(url))
tickets = data['eventTicketListing']['eventTicket']

prices = [ticket['tc']['amount'] for ticket in tickets]
print(sorted(prices))
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rcarmody\Desktop\Python\Tickets\tix_seatgeak.py", line 24, in <module>
    data = json.load(urlopen(url))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 214, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 523, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 632, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 561, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Answer (score 0):

1. This link redirects to an actual webpage. Are you meaning to use `api.stubhub.com` instead of `www.stubhub.com`
2. you aren't sending credentials with the request. This explains the 403. Web error code 403 is a credentials error of some kind. You need to include credentials in your request via JSON.